# Lubuntu alternate installer torrent tracker error

Tags: lubuntu, iso, bittorrent, transmission, alternate

I received the error:
Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker.

When opening the link at:
http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/xenial/release/lubuntu-16.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent

In transmission.
I was able to open the link to and successfully download the desktop iso from:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/yakkety/release/lubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Maybe the alternate installer iso is somehow disabled on the tracker?
I was able to download the installer via the hhtp link but it was very slow (~300kbps).

Answer (score 3):

The following link is a better alternative to get Lubuntu with the Xenial kernel,

http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/xenial/release/lubuntu-16.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent

This torrent file provides a version that is more debugged and polished compared to the original 16.04 LTS version, and there is no complaint about the torrent file, when using it in Transmission. (12 clients were feeding the torrent, and the iso file was good, when I checked it with md5sum afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

I just received this error.  I had already downloaded 100% of mine, but it stopped seeding with that "not authorized" error.

I checked https://lubuntu.net/downloads/ and saw there was a new Lubuntu version.

Downloading the new torrent from https://lubuntu.net/downloads/ worked as-expected.  I'm now downloading and seeding the new version.